# Using JDBC to connect to SQL database that has a firewall

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm currently doing some testing and I want automate some queries of a database. Currently the server I want to connect to has a firewall blocking it so I'm a little confused on how I should set my JDBC and MYSQL Workbench set up. I'm wondering can anyone give me some advice on what I should be trying to do to successfully connect to the remote DB.

Comment: you need to get the ports open through the firewall to work with the MySQL

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, pls give more context on expected output vs actual output (errors you seeing, what type of settings in place atm, code/config if applicable too, ect). Also, prob more a Super User or Server Fault question, not a programming question as such. See link in this sites footer and read tour page or home page or wherever it described the type of issues (prob already solved there too)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, have you attempted connecting to the SQL database? If so, do you get an error like

```
SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host localhost, port (number) has failed. Error: "Connection refused: connect. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.
```

Do you control the server, or have contact with the people who control the server? I had the same problem as you and fixed it by going to the server firewall settings and allowing `<port-number>` thru the firewall, then set my JDBC connection string as

```
 Server=myServerAddress;Port=<port-number>;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;
```

I use SQL Server, not MySQL, but i think it's a matter of ports, and not your database management system.

Comment: what do you mean by "? I had the same problem as you and fixed it by going to the server firewall settings and allowing <port-number> thru the firewall" there is a file on the server which specifies the open port. What should I do?

Comment: I'm the admin of my application server and it's running Windows Server 2012. So i opened the "Windows Firewall' app within the Control Panel and allowed my application port number to bypass the firewall. If you know which port is open, then simply modify your JDBC connection string and include the port number, after the host name.

Answer (score 1):

JDBC has nothing to do with firewalls or other network related structure. In order to connect properly to the database server, the current computer trying to connect should have access and enough privileges to the database server. Talk to system administrator or other personal in charge of solving this networking issue.